# Asking a question: DO or ARE?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

When should you ask a question with "do", and when with "are"?  In other words,

> Are you going to Spain next week?

> Do you like Chinese food?

What is the rule here?  We don't say

> Do you go to Spain next week?

> Are you liking Chinese food?

Why is that?

Comment: *Are you liking Chinese food?* is probably never idiomatic outside of "Indian English", but *Do you go to Spain next week?* can certainly be perfectly natural in some contexts (for example, with ***you*** emphasised, within a conversation where it's already been mentioned that *some* [other] people are indeed going to Spain next week).

Comment: ...others may think different, but in the context I put forward above I think the nuance of difference between 1) *Do you go to Spain next week?* and 2) *Are you going to Spain next week?* is that the ***do-*** version focuses more on *your current status* (as one of the people selected to go next week), where the ***as-*** version puts more emphasis on the matter of *something you might or will do in the future*.

Comment: And then there's the McDonald's commercial, "I'm Lovin' It"

Answer (score 5):

As statements, your two examples would be:

> - You like Chinese food
> - You are going to Spain next week

Next, find the main verb:

> - You **like** Chinese food
> - You **are** going to Spain next week

Now you need to figure out if the verb is an [auxiliary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_auxiliaries_and_contractions) verb. If it is, then it is what's inverted in [subject-auxiliary inversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subject%E2%80%93auxiliary_inversion):

> - Are you going to Spain next week?

If there is no auxiliary, you need to add the proper form of *do*. It will be the auxiliary that is inverted:

> - Do you like Chinese food?

---

#### This is a type of [*do*-support](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Do-support#In_questions).

Comment: What about **need**? **"I need a rope"** we can either ask **"Need you a rope?"** or **"Do you need a rope?"**

Comment: @SovereignSun That's part of figuring out if something is a modal or not. But it is tricky, since some verbs are modals in some cases and not in others. As [this post](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/29413/191178) explains, *need* is sometimes modal, sometimes not. Another example is *do*, as it is not a modal in "You did your homework". Therefore, "Did you your homework?" is wrong, while "Did you do your homework?" is right.